# How to add logo to AppBar in Vuetify?

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a `v-app-bar` control, and I'm trying to add a logo/image to it.

Is there a standard approach in Veutify for adding a logo to the AppBar?

Comment: please share some code. What have you tried? Refer to this guide on providing a verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqBrvr?&editable=true&editors=101#anon-login

Answer (score 26):

You can add a [`v-img`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images#images) component like this:

```html
<v-app-bar color="light-blue lighten-3" app>

  <v-img
    class="mx-2"
    src="https://i.imgur.com/qgGY4tB.png"
    max-height="40"
    max-width="40"
    contain
  ></v-img>

  <v-toolbar-title class="ml-2">
    Page title
  </v-toolbar-title>

</v-app-bar>
```

It's important to set a `max-height` and `max-width`, otherwise the image will overflow the nav vertically and push over the title horizontally. And also set `contain` to preserve the aspect ratio

#### [Demo in CodePen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/jgmRjV?editors=1000)

[image]

> **Note**: If you're using Nuxt/Webpack, etc, you might need to build the image path with something like this: `:src="require('~/assets/logo.png')"`

Comment: FYI it bothered me to hard-code the height to `40` but it looks like that's a pretty reasonable value for a variety of screen sizes and zooms.

Comment: Is there a solution without hardcoding the value? I was hoping there was a way to make a v-img inherit its parent's height and keep aspect ratio.

Answer (score 4):

Use `v-avatar` with a `tile` property set to `true`, just like this:

```html
<v-avatar :tile="true">
  <img :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')" alt="logo">
</v-avatar>
```

The full `v-app-bar` example:

```html
<v-app-bar app light>
  <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
  <v-avatar :tile="true">
    <img :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')" alt="logo">
  </v-avatar>
  <v-toolbar-title>Header text</v-toolbar-title>
</v-app-bar>
```

Comment: This is really tiny if your logo is a rectangle. Would not recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Yon can juste use the `<img>` balise from native html to set your logo.

Then you can resize them with `width` or `height` property.